# Button starts automatically when entering page

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two components (app and navbar).
When I click on a table row a timer starts. I want to present this timer in all other components, so I created in the service a function that returns the value of User and can thus present the timer in all components.

My problem is that when I start the page, the navbar button starts counting automatically and I don't know why. This button should only work / display results when something is clicked on the app component.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

**My code [LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqoaaf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnavbar%2Fnavbar.component.ts)**

**app service**

```
 this.currentUserId = new BehaviorSubject<string>(undefined);

 setUserId(id: string): void {
    this.currentUserId.next(id);
  }
```

**app component**

```
  startTimer(data) {
    this.currentusertime = data.key.ID;
    this.taskService.iduser = data.key.ID;
    this.taskService.startTimer(data.key.ID);
  }

  pauseTimer(data) {
     this.taskService.iduser = data.key.ID;
    this.taskService.pauseTimer(data.key.ID);
  }

  rowClicked(event: any): void {
    this.taskService.setUserId(event.data.ID);
  }
```

**navbar component**

```
  constructor(public taskService: TaskService) { 
    this.taskService.currentUserId.subscribe(x => {
      this.userId = x;
      this.startTimer();
    });
  }
```

As you can see in the image, the button on the navbar is already active, not knowing why. It should only be enabled when something is clicked on the app component table :(

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening because you are using a `BehaviourSubject`. It calls all subscriptions with a starting value or the current value if it has changed. In your case, your `this.taskService.currentUserId.subscribe(x => {` will be called with `undefined` when the page loads. An easy workaround would be to filter out `undefined` values.

You can actually test that behaviour by printing out your `taskService.timerForUsers` array. This shows that a key `undefined` is actually created: `{ "undefined": { "currentState": "start", "currentTime": 75, "initialTime": 20, "startTime": "1578143992066", "interval": 134 } }`

```
  constructor(public taskService: TaskService) { 
    this.taskService.currentUserId.pipe(
      filter(x => !!x) // subscribe will not trigger when x is falsy
    ).subscribe(x => {
      this.userId = x;
      this.startTimer();
    });
  }
```

Working [Stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqpgvv).

Comment: There is only one problem, when I start the counter and then refresh the page, it doesn't get the same value as the component running in the app component. Do you know why? Thank you for your big help!

Comment: You are not saving the userId as you save the users themselves. When the page reloads, the value in the behaviour subject is back to `undefined`. You have to save the value as well.

Comment: Here another Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvdfnd

Comment: Once you get the hang of it, it actually is. Just the learning curve is a bit steep. You're welcome! :)

Comment: Good thing there are people who still like to help others!

Comment: You helped me pass the user ID and store it in local storage. I created in the datasource an image field, which contains the image of the user, tried to pass the image and the name of the user, just as it did with the ID, but even navbar as undefined ... What could it be? If you prefer I can create a new topic

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in `TaskService` the `startTimer()` triggers once you open the `NavBar` component. So in this way the `*ngIf` does not pass for the following:

```
*ngIf="taskService.getCurrentState() === 'pause' || taskService.getCurrentState() === undefined"
```

For the mentioned `*ngIf` if the `getCurrentState()` returns `pause` or `undefined` then it should represent the `play` button. But you have a different value `start`.

In `TaskService` you have the following:

```
startTimer(userId:string) {   
    // ... rest
    currentUserTimer.currentState = 'start';
    this.state = currentUserTimer.currentState;
    // ... rest
}
```

That's why you have `start` value for `getCurrentState()`.

I hope that helps!